# How can I export my gradient to get the colour values from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, cs5, swatches

I would like to export my gradient from Illustrator CS5.  I know I can click each swatch individually, make a note of the colour and the percentage value and click on each handle to work out the value for that, but is there an easier or better way of doing this?

One concern I have is moving the swatch or handle by accident.

Ideally I'd like to be able to replicate the swatch in InDesign CS5 but also on websites and other programs.

What's the best way to achieve this?

[image: my rose gold gradient]

Note: although the angle shows as 0° I have put maybe a 43° angle on it.  Not sure why it no longer shows.

Comment: Good answer.  But then how would I export it?  I need the colours values and positions so I can make a web based gradient right?

Comment: And also save the swatch so I might import it to Photoshop or InDesign?

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to copy "gradient properties" from Illustrator into Photoshop or InDesign, would be pretty cool if you could.

Comment: You can fill a shape and copy and paste it. But how to copy  it to web is less obvious. I fuess I'll have to do it manually.

Comment: My first thought was [Colorzilla Gradient Editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)... it has image import below the gradient editor. Never tried to import complex gradients tho.. no idea how well it handles those. Not sure if it fits your workflow. Since you mentioned Photoshop, there is an extension for it called: [CSS Hat](https://csshat.com). PS does have it's own copy CSS function too.

Comment: Fair one I'll try using coliurzilla and if not I'll try Photoshop. Both good shouts. If either works I'll ask you to answer.

Comment: You inspired me and Ifound this too  http://gradientfinder.com

Comment: I thought I'd do a little testing between the 2 gradient editor web apps and their image imports. It seems Colorzilla is more liberal with the color- and opacity-stops but is way more accurate. I used a gradient with some low opacity stops and GradientFinder kept forgetting some stops leaving some parts translucent when they weren't supposed to be. And to paint a better picture of how liberal Colorzilla is with the stops... My 4 color stop and 4 opacity stop gradient was converted to CSS with 20 color stops and 15 opacity stops, but at least it was pretty accurate.

Comment: Put it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess between Illustrator, Indesign and Photoshop, there isn't really a proper way to transfer gradients, because all of them handle gradients differently. I kinda don't understand this workflow where you need to do this, but I guess I would just copy & paste the object (or a layer) from one application to another.

Generating CSS (Gradient):

- **Image to CSS Gradient:** [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator - ColorZilla.com](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

  - If you have an image of the gradient, upload it using the `import image` link and the gradient is converted to CSS.
  - Supports linear gradients that are vertical or horizontal.
- **Photoshop**

  1. [Copy CSS (native)](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/copy-css-shape-or-text.html): `Right Click layer > Copy CSS`

     - Can get a gradient from a layer style or from a shape layer with a gradient fill
  2. [CSS Hat](https://csshat.com/)
  3. [Dreamweaver (CC, I believe) can extract css from a psd](https://helpx.adobe.com/sea/dreamweaver/how-to/copy-css-from-psd.html).
- **Illustrator**

  - [Copy CSS (native)](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/css-extraction.html): Top menu `Window > CSS Properties`

    - Additional options in the corner menu of this panel.
- **Indesign**

  - There is no CSS export for InDesign.

Comment: There is no CSS Properties in Illustrator CS5.  The same with Photoshop.  It's a shame Colourzilla doesn't work with rotated gradients, but I guess if that's the only variable to work out then at least you have a fighting chance (although the hardest variable to work out).  I can grab that easily from Illustrator.  Great answer.

Comment: @Eoin, Yea, I'm not sure if the Copy CSS feature was released in CS6. It is definitely in CC. CSS Hat 1 does support PS CS5, not sure about what features that had though. **—** You can always make your Radial gradient Linear, export that as an image and tell Colorzilla to make it a Radial CSS gradient.

Comment: Joonas it is a linear gradient.  It just has an angle on it.  So it kind of goes from centre bottom left to centre top right.  It's ok though, that's easy enough to work out just by looking at the angle.  I think that was really the answer.

Comment: @Eoin, right... I read what I wanted to read... Same thing though. you should import the gradient as perfectly vertical or horizontal and give it the angle later. This is something I didn't realize until now, but Colorzilla's gradient editor doesn't allow you to define a custom angle, but GradientFinder does. Of course, you can always edit the code it spews out.....